# Почему не работает карусель в ИЕ7?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Учусь верстать, сделала верстку макета. Единственное, что у меня не получилось, - настроить слайдер [Carousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) в IE7, не могу разобраться, в чем там дело, в ие8, 9 и других браузерах слайдер работает.
Верстка с неработающим в ие7 плагином лежит здесь http://rghost.ru/41673813
При открытии страницы в ие7 выпадает следующая ошибка
[image]

**Строка: 609
Ошибка: jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting..**.

Comment: "Файл удалён"

Comment: @ХэшКод, в теле сообщения есть жалоба на не работающий плагин в ИЕ7 и с этим можно было человеку помочь. Проблема в том, что тема не называется "Почему не работает карусель в ИЕ7?". Люди учатся, задаюсь вопросы и спрашивают мнение. Думал, для этого и нужен Хэшкод. Уж лучше такие темы, чем 100500 тем с заголовком "ааааа, у меня не работает @font-face". И там даже не пытаются воспользоваться поиском - прежде чем задать вопрос.

Comment: вот последняя версия верстки. с непонятным поведением тизера в ие7 http://rghost.ru/41677367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошая верстка. Не оценивал ее на предмет кроссбраузерности - это вы сами можете сделать. Смотрел общий стиль - хороший. Единственное что бы я поменял это:

1. убрать hover эффект с активного пункта меню в шапке (что бы не пропадала голубая стрелка вниз) и можно даже курсор менять на дэфолтный, а не руку)
2. Списки в тексте сделать списками через UL, а не через BR. Это касается перечней "что мы производим", "развеять сомнения".

UPD: Карусели в ИЕ7 - поправьте инициализацию плагина. 
initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,}); После последней строки не должно быть запятой.

UPD2: По какой-то причине Карусель не может определить ширину элементов которые прокручивает в ИЕ7. Есть свойство itemFallbackDimension. думаю стоит воспользоваться им и в нем указать ширину элемента который прокручивается.

**itemFallbackDimension** If, for some reason, jCarousel can not detect the width of an item, you can set a fallback dimension (width or height, depending on the orientation) here to ensure correct calculations.

[В самом низу страницы](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

Comment: Да, спасибо, активный пункт меню в шапке поправила, курсор на нем на дефолтный поменяла, списки в тексте сделала. По кроссбраузерности все постаралсь сделать, главная проблема - это не работающая в ие7 карусель.
По карусели: запятую убрала, но всё равно в ие7 она не работает, теперь выпадает ошибка, я добавила в топик ссылку на скрин ошибки и текст ошибки. Причем, находит ошибку в скрипте самой карусели. Эта ошибка означает, что для какого элемента нужно задать размеры, или что-то еще?

Comment: Ие7 не справляется с определением размеров блока, автоматически. Можно искать причину в плагине, но быстрее попробовать воспользоваться itemFallbackDimension. Если не поможет тогда разбираться детальнее.

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло, но лишь отчасти - куда-то пропала правая кнопка (nextButton) на карусели, а при клике на левую управляющую кнопку (prevButtom) либо ничего не происходит, либо пропадает вообще все содержимое карусели (дивы teaserText и teaserImage), и остается только кнопка prevButtom.

Comment: А, всё, правую управляющую кнопку нашла, она почему-то куда-то уехала, прописала в таблице стилей для ие7 для новое расстояние .jcarousel-next {left: 870px;}, она встала на место.

Comment: Смена изображений в тизере все еще непонятно работает. Там сейчас прописано три пункта <li></li>, в которых лежит то, что крутится в карусели. При открытии страницы в ие7 первые три или четыре тизера проезжают плавно друг за другом, потом последний уезжает, а следующий не появляется, хотя у карусели стоит wrap: 'circular' и он отрабатывает в других браузерах. А тут последний тизер уезжает, потом некоторое время - пустое место, потом выезжает следующий, потом опять пустое место и тд.